# Unable to submit Spark job from Windows IDE to Linux cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I just read about [findspark](https://www.davidadrian.cc/posts/2017/08/how-to-spark-cluster/) and found it quite interesting, as so far I have only used `spark-submit` which isn't be suited for interactive development on an IDE. I tried executing this file on Windows 10, Anaconda 4.4.0, Python 3.6.1, IPython 5.3.0, Spyder 3.1.4, Spark 2.1.1:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1

import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local',
                          appName='test1')

print(repr(sc.parallelize(tuple(range(10))).map(inc).collect()))
```

Spyder generates the command `runfile('C:/tests/temp1.py', wdir='C:/tests')` and it prints out `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` as expected. However if I try to use a Spark cluster running on Ubuntu I get an error:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1

import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='spark://192.168.1.57:7077',
                          appName='test1')

print(repr(sc.parallelize(tuple(range(10))).map(inc).collect()))
```

IPython errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-820bd4275b8c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/tests/temp.py', wdir='C:/tests')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/tests/temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(repr(sc.parallelize(tuple(range(10))).map(inc).collect()))

  File "C:\projects\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 808, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())

  File "C:\projects\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "C:\projects\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
```

Worker stderr:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For some reason this is trying to use a Windows binary path on Linux slave. Any ideas how to overcome this? I get the same outcome with Python console on Spyder, except the error is `Cannot run program "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory`. Actually it happends from command line as well, when running `python temp.py`.

This version works fine even when submitted from Windows to Linux:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName='test2')

print(repr(sc.parallelize(tuple(range(10))).map(inc).collect()))
```

`spark-submit --master spark://192.168.1.57:7077 temp2.py`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, which turned out to be very simple. [pyspark/context.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/python/pyspark/context.py#L193) uses env variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to determine the Python executable's path, but defaults to the "correct" `python`. However by default findspark [overrides](https://github.com/minrk/findspark/blob/1.1.0/findspark.py#L130) this env variable to match `sys.executable`, which clearly won't work cross-platform.

Anyway here is the working code for future reference:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1

import findspark
findspark.init(python_path='python') # <-- so simple!

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='spark://192.168.1.57:7077',
                          appName='test1')

print(repr(sc.parallelize(tuple(range(10))).map(inc).collect()))
```